Overlap of two circles on a sphere
If we have, in the plane, two circles of radius $R$ which are separated by a distance $d$ then its easy to compute the overlapping area:
$$\frac{A}{R^2} = 2\arccos\left(\frac{d}{2R}\right) - 2\left(\frac{d}{2R}\right)\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{d}{2R}\right)^2}$$
for $d/2 \leq R$ and zero otherwise (see e.g. this).
Is there a know analytical result for the corresponding overlap of two circles on a sphere?
We can try to compute it by placing two circles with radius $R$ equidistant from the equator: one a distance $d/2$ over and one a distance $d/2$ under the equator. The distances here are the distances on the sphere which is the same as angles on the unit sphere. The overlap form a lens-shaped region that is symmetric about the equator. Some simple geometry gives us (if I did this correctly)
$$A = 4\int_0^{\sin\alpha} \arccos\left(\frac{\cos(R)/\cos(d/2) + \tan(d/2)x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)dx$$
where $\alpha = R-d/2$. A simple check: when $d=0$ and $R\ll 1$ (the flat-sky limit with full overlap) this reduces to $A \simeq \pi R^2$ as expected. Similary if $R = d/2$ then we get $A = 0$. Is there some (managable) analytical result for this integral?
Mathematica can produce some long answer, but its a monster and not easy to simplify. Surely this problem has some simpler answer than 3 pages of formulas?

Edit: If we take the result for the integral derived by user170231 below and simplify it further then we can arrive at the very simple result
$$\boxed{A = 4\arccos\left[\frac{\sin(d/2)}{\sin(R)}\right] - 4\cos(R)\arccos\left[\frac{\tan(d/2)}{\tan(R)}\right]}$$
Fixing $\beta \equiv d/2R$ and then taking the limit $R\to 0$ of $A/R^2$ then we recover exactly the flat-sky result quoted at the top of this answer which is a good check of the result.

I think your formula is correct. I went to the trouble of setting up a surface integral that collapsed into essentially the same expression, up to my choice in parameters. Integration by parts and Euler substituting next seems like a reasonable thing to try.

@user170231 That's great, thanks for checking it!

Proceed with integration by parts,
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal I(a,b) &= 4 \int_0^{\sin\alpha} \arccos \frac{a+bv}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \, dv \\
&= 4\sin\alpha \arccos \left(a\sec\alpha+b\tan\alpha\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac2{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \int_0^{\sin\alpha} \frac{v(b+av)}{\left(1-v^2\right) \sqrt{A - B v - v^2}} \, dv
\end{align*}$$
where
$$(A,B):=\left(\dfrac{1-a^2}{1+b^2},\dfrac{2ab}{1+b^2}\right).$$
Decompose part of the integrand into partial fractions,
$$\frac{v(b+av)}{1-v^2} = \frac{a+b}{1-v} + \frac{a-b}{1+v}-2a,$$
then utilize an Euler substitution,
$$v=-\frac12 \cdot \frac{\omega^+ + \omega^- t^2}{1+t^2} \iff t = \sqrt{-\frac{\omega^++2v}{\omega^-+2v}}, \tag{$*$}$$
where $\omega^\pm = B\pm\sqrt{4A+B^2}$, to evaluate the remaining integrals:
$$\begin{align*}
I(k) &= \int_0^{\sin\alpha} \frac{dv}{(1+kv) \sqrt{A-Bv-v^2}} \\
&= \int_0^{\sqrt{-\tfrac{\omega^-}{\omega^+}}} \frac{4\,dt}{\left(2-k\omega^-\right) + \left(2-k\omega^+\right) t^2} & (*) \\
&= \frac2{\sqrt{1-Bk-Ak^2}} \arctan \sqrt{-\frac{2kA+\omega^-}{2kA+\omega^+}}
\end{align*}$$
The vanishing lower limit as $v\to\sin\alpha$ follows from the simplification
$$\sqrt{-\frac{\omega^++2\sin\alpha}{\omega^-+2\sin\alpha}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sin\left(\color{red}{R-\frac d2}\right) - \sin\alpha}{\sin\left(R+\frac d2\right) + \sin\alpha}}.$$
Now use
$$1\pm B-A=\dfrac{(a\pm b)^2}{1+b^2} \\
\arccos x = 2 \arctan \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}$$
to reduce the integral to
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal I(a,b) &= 4\sin\alpha \arccos \left(a\sec\alpha+b\tan\alpha\right) \\
&\qquad + \frac2{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \bigg[(a+b)I(-1) + (a-b) I(1) - 2a I(0)\bigg] \\[2ex]
&= 2\pi + 4\sin\alpha \arccos \left(a\sec\alpha+b\tan\alpha\right) \\ 
&\qquad  + 2 \arccos\frac{1-a^2+ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2}} - 2 \arccos\frac{1-a^2-ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2}} \\
&\qquad - \frac{4a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}} \arccos \frac{ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2}
}
\end{align*}$$
As pointed out in comments, the middle $\arccos$ terms may be joined as
$$2 \arccos\frac{1-a^2+ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2}} - 2 \arccos\frac{1-a^2-ab}{\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2}} = -2 \arccos \frac{1-a^2-b^2}{1-a^2+b^2}.$$
Plugging in $a=\dfrac{\cos R}{\cos\frac d2}$ and $b=\tan\dfrac d2$, we find
$$\begin{align*}
\text{area} &= \bbox[#ffd83b,2pt]{
2\pi - 2 \arccos \frac{R^2-1+\cos d}{R^2} - 4\sqrt{1-R^2} \arccos \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-R^2}}R \tan \frac d2\right)
}
\end{align*}$$

Small thing: I think you have accidentally made the replacement $\sin(R) \to R$ in the final result (i.e. you need to change $R\to \sin(R)$ to get the correct form) .
